# TcpClient.NetworkStream Async operations - Canceling / Disconnect

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, tcpclient

Disclaimer: My C# isn't even close to as good as my C++

I am trying to learn how to do async sockets in C# in order to write a test app for a component of mine. I read about a variety of methods, but it seems the most modern is to use TcpClient, get the NetworkStream from it, and call async methods on the NetworkStream that return Task.

So, I set off on my adventure.

It is not clear how to cancel the async methods properly or if I need to. Am I supposed to manually cancel them when I want to disconnect? One would think TcpClient.Close would take care of that in some graceful way for me.

If I do use the manual cancellation, then it seems there is some mechanism needed to wait until all the async methods exit before the main thread continues on. Noted in the listing in the Disconnect() method. The result is that the main thread continues on disposing and exiting before MakeRequest() or Read() have exited, and therefore exceptions about using disposed objects.

In my test without manual cancellation, I get the same exception from the async read, about using an object that has been disposed, because the main thread still continues on disposing and exiting before those methods are exited.

I suppose I could put in my own synchronization mechanism...but what is the proper way to do this? Should I be cancelling at all? Is there some built in way to wait for those methods to exit? What did they expect us to do?

Here is my latest code attempt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using log4net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    public class Client
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("root");

        static private ulong m_lastId = 1;

        private ulong m_id;
        private string m_host;
        private uint m_port;
        private uint m_timeoutMilliseconds;
        private string m_clientId;
        private TcpClient m_tcpClient;
        private CancellationTokenSource m_cancelationSource;

        public Client(string host, uint port, string clientId, uint timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            m_id = m_lastId++;
            m_host = host;
            m_port = port;
            m_clientId = clientId;
            m_timeoutMilliseconds = timeoutMilliseconds;
            m_tcpClient = null;
            m_cancelationSource = null;
        }

        ~Client()
        {
            Disconnect();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to connect to the hostname and port specified in the constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <throws cref="System.ApplicationException" on failure
        public void Connect()
        {
            Disconnect();

            m_tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            m_cancelationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            try
            {
                m_tcpClient.Connect(m_host, (int)m_port);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                string msg = string.Format("Client #{0} failed to connect to {1} on port {2}"
                                          , m_id, m_host, m_port);
                throw new System.ApplicationException(msg, e);
            }

            if (m_tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                log.Debug(string.Format("Client #{0} connnected to the Component on {1}"
                                      , m_id, m_tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            if (m_cancelationSource != null)
            {
                m_cancelationSource.Cancel();

                // TODO - There needs to be some kind of wait here until the async methods all return!
                //        How to do that?
                //        Are we even supposed to be manually canceling? One would think TcpClient.Close takes care of that,
                //        however when deleting all cancelation stuff, instead we get exceptions from the async methods about
                //        using TcpClient's members after it was disposed.

                m_cancelationSource.Dispose();
                m_cancelationSource = null;
            }

            if (m_tcpClient != null)
            {
                m_tcpClient.Close();
                m_tcpClient = null;
            }
        }

        public void Login()
        {
            string loginRequest = string.Format("loginstuff{0}", m_clientId);
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginRequest);

            NetworkStream stream = m_tcpClient.GetStream();
            Task writeTask = stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Count());

            // This will block until the login is sent
            // We want block until the login is sent, so we can be sure we logged in before making requests
            if( !writeTask.Wait((int)m_timeoutMilliseconds) )
            {
                // Error - Send timed out
                log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Timed out while sending login request to the Component"
                                      , m_id));
            }
            else
            {
                log.Debug(string.Format("Client #{0} sent login request to the Component"
                                       , m_id));
            }
        }

        public async void Read()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            NetworkStream networkStream = m_tcpClient.GetStream();
            Task<int> readTask = null;

            bool disconnected = false;

            try
            {
                while (!disconnected)
                {
                    readTask = networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, m_cancelationSource.Token);
                    int bytesReceived = await readTask;

                    if (readTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                    {
                        if( bytesReceived <= 0)
                        {
                            disconnected = true;
                            continue;
                        }

                        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);

                        // TODO - Handle parsing of messages in the memory stream

                        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    }
                    else if (readTask.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled)
                    {
                        // Error - Read was cancelled
                        log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Read operation was canceled."
                                              , m_id));
                        disconnected = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Error - Unexpected status
                        log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Read operation has unexpected status after returning from await."
                                              , m_id));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught while reading from socket. Exception: {1}"
                                       , m_id, e.ToString()));
            }
        }

        public async void MakeRequest(string thingy)
        {
            string message = string.Format("requeststuff{0}", thingy);
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            NetworkStream networkStream = m_tcpClient.GetStream();
            Task writeTask = null;

            try
            {
                writeTask = networkStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Count(), m_cancelationSource.Token);
                await writeTask;

                if (writeTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    log.Debug(string.Format("Client #{0} sent request for thingy {1} to the Component"
                                           , m_id, thingy));
                }
                else if (writeTask.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled)
                {
                    // Error - Write was cancelled
                    log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Write operation was canceled while requesting thingy {1} from the Component"
                                          , m_id, thingy));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Error - Unexpected status
                    log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Write operation has unexpected status after returning from await, while requesting thingy {1} from the Component"
                                          , m_id, thingy));
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(string.Format("Client #{0} Exception caught while requesting thingy {1}. Exception: {2}" 
                                       , m_id, thingy, e.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("root");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlConfigurator.Configure();
                log.Info("Starting Component Integration Tests...");

                Client client = new Client("127.0.0.1", 24001, "MyClientId", 60000);
                client.Connect();

                client.Read();
                client.Login();
                client.MakeRequest("Stuff");

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);

                client.Disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(string.Format("Caught an exception in main. Exception: {0}"
                                      , e.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the overloads of `WriteAsync` takes a `CancellationToken` to cancel the call. `TcpClient` implements `IDisposable` so you need to call `Dispose` on it when you get rid of it. You should protect those places with `try..finally` to ensure that you clean up resources.

Comment: Yes, I read that. However, it is not clear how to use the cancelation token to cancel and when to cancel. Do I need to cancel when I disconnect or is that already done automatically? Also, if an exception is thrown how is it handled when the main thread's execution pointer has moved on passed the call the the async method?

Comment: The caller will get the exception in either case - if you use `await`, exceptions in the async call will get marshaled back to the caller. I don't understand your questions about when to cancel - you cancel when you want to cancel the call. If you disconnect the socket, it'll drop connections; that's not canceling. You still need to call `Dispose`, though.

Comment: "when I want to cancel"....Ok, when _do I_ want to cancel? If the connection drops, is the process still attempting to write to the network buffer? do I get an exception? where do I catch it?

You say I get exceptions from the caller to indicate error, but If I pull the plug, no breakpoint in any catch block is hit and everything continues as if it was successful, yet my server was shutdown.